# a4j:commandbutton with only icon and no text

Tags: jsf-2

How can I show icon on the a4j:commandButton. 
I don't want text on the button.

```
<a4j:commandButton id="editLink" styleClass="buttonImage"
                   action="#{bean.populateForm}"
                   oncomplete=" #{rich:component('EditPopup')}.show();"
                   render="EditPopup" execute="@form">
</a4j:commandButton>
```

and below code for styleClass

```
 .buttonImage   {background-image: url(../images/edit.gif)!important}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions are

- give the image as `image`-attribute with the `a4j:commandButton` and skip the css-part
- set the attribute `value=" "` and adapt the css-style

For adapting the css, style, try (imagewidth being your images actual width)

```
.buttonImage   {
    background-image: url(../images/edit.gif)!important}
    width: <imagewidth>px;
}
```

Hope that helps...